# Hot tub circuit breaker in sub panel trips after 5 hours

Tags: circuit-breaker, subpanel, hot-tub

I have a 2 year old hot tub and the sub panel keeps tripping after the hot tub runs for a few hours. The heater, ozonator and sub panel circuit breaker were replaced to try to fix the problem but it’s still tripping. The main panel circuit breaker does not trip. When I first discovered the problem (hot tub shut down), the control panel was not working due to water damage. When the control panel was replaced, the circuit breaker continued to trip.

Comment: Does the circuit breaker that is tripping have a "Test" button?  If so, search the web for a procedure to detect the reason for the trip. Most newer breakers have that.  We can narrow it down to overcurrent, GFCI etc.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when the breaker trips, it's NOT due to a faulty breaker, but a breaker that's doing its job. *Eventually* breakers do wear out, but it's unlikely after only 2 years. Sometimes a bad breaker leaves the factory, but, in general, either of these is pretty rare.

Have you had the heater, ozonator, pumps and other electrical gubbins inspected for loose connections? Odds are good that's your problem.

If you had an electrician come look at your problem and his solution was to replace the spa panel, he's busting a gut laughing right now. He did the minimal work necessary and made a tidy profit on parts markup. Call out a *different* electrician and tell her you need her to do a full inspection of all components.

Or, if you're comfortable with a DIY approach, turn off the main breaker at the spa panel, open it up and check every single connection inside the panel and at every receptacle, switch, motor, heater, whatever, attached to the panel.

Once you've made sure no wires are pull-out loose, get your torque screwdriver and torque all the screws down according to their specs. The specs will be on the panel and/or breakers and may be listed on the individual parts. If they're not, search the web for `torque spec <brand> <model>` and you'll find them, most likely on the manufacturer's web site.

Comment: You appear to think OP had a subpanel replaced, but from what I can tell the OP had a part of the hot tub (the control panel) replaced.

Comment: "sub panel circuit breaker were replaced" @GlennWillen. As far as I can tell, that means the breaker was replace. I guess I was a bit broad in stating that the "panel" was replaced. In either case, assuming a breaker has failed because it trips is, 99% of the time, the wrong assumption.